# How do I rotate something 15 degrees in Flutter?

Tags: dart, flutter

The Flutter docs show an example of rotating a "div" by 15 degrees, both for HTML/CSS and Flutter code:

The Flutter code is:

```
var container = new Container( // gray box
  child: new Center(
    child:  new Transform(
      child:  new Text(
        "Lorem ipsum",
      ),
      alignment: FractionalOffset.center,
      transform: new Matrix4.identity()
        ..rotateZ(15 * 3.1415927 / 180),
    ), 
  ),
);
```

And the relevant parts are `new Transform` and `alignment: FractionalOffset.center` and `transform: new Matrix4.identity()..rotateZ(15 * 3.1415927 / 180)`

I'm curious, is there a simpler way to rotate a `Container` in Flutter? Is there a short-hand for the case of "15 degrees" ?

Thanks!

Comment: Not even a single answer works! Any solution?

Answer (score 226, accepted):

In mobile apps, I think it's kind of rare to have things start out rotated 15 degrees and just stay there forever. So that may be why Flutter's support for rotation is better if you're planning to adjust the rotation over time.

It feels like overkill, but a [`RotationTransition`](https://api.flutter.dev/flutter/widgets/RotationTransition-class.html) with an [`AlwaysStoppedAnimation`](https://api.flutter.dev/flutter/animation/AlwaysStoppedAnimation-class.html) would accomplish exactly what you want.

[image: screenshot]

```
new RotationTransition(
  turns: new AlwaysStoppedAnimation(15 / 360),
  child: new Text("Lorem ipsum"),
)
```

If you want to rotate something 90, 180, or 270 degrees, you can use a [`RotatedBox`](https://api.flutter.dev/flutter/widgets/RotatedBox-class.html).

[image: screenshot]

```
new RotatedBox(
  quarterTurns: 1,
  child: new Text("Lorem ipsum")
)
```

Comment: Do you know what the performance impact is of using a RotationTransition vs Transform?

Comment: The performance difference should be negligible. If you look under the hood the code for RotationTransition is almost exactly the same. The only difference is a few additional objects will be constructed (RotationTransition and AlwaysStoppedAnimation), which is very cheap in Dart. Because the animation never changes, the RotationTransition will only build itself once.

Comment: Note: the RotatedBox widget quarter is equivalent to 0, 90, 180, 270 degrees, unfortunately not suitable for other angles (like 15° or 45° for example)

Answer (score 162):

You can use `Transform.rotate` to rotate your widget. I used `Text` and rotated it with 45˚ (π/4)

Example:

```dart
import 'dart:math' as math;

Transform.rotate(
  angle: -math.pi / 4,
  child: Text('Text'),
)
```

[image]

Comment: Best answer here, worked flawlessly!

Answer (score 22):

[image]

If you are working with a canvas ([as in a CustomPaint widget](https://medium.com/@suragch/how-to-paint-in-flutter-d18c6c26df10)), you can rotate 15 degrees like this:

```
import 'dart:math' as math;

class MyPainter extends CustomPainter {
  @override
  void paint(Canvas canvas, Size size) {
    canvas.save();

    // rotate the canvas
    final degrees = 15;
    final radians = degrees * math.pi / 180;
    canvas.rotate(radians);

    // draw the text
    final textStyle = TextStyle(color: Colors.black, fontSize: 30);
    final textSpan = TextSpan(text: 'Hello, world.', style: textStyle);
    TextPainter(text: textSpan, textDirection: TextDirection.ltr)
      ..layout(minWidth: 0, maxWidth: size.width)
      ..paint(canvas, Offset(0, 0));

    canvas.restore();
  }

  @override
  bool shouldRepaint(CustomPainter old) {
    return false;
  }
}
```

However, if you are doing something simple then I would use a `RotatedBox` or `Transform.rotate` as suggested by the other answers.

Answer (score 17):

There is Two Main Flutter Widget available for this functionality, **RotationTransition** and **Transform.rotate**

another supported option is **RotatedBox** but this rotate widget only
supports quarter turns, which means they support vertical and only horizontal orientation.
and if you rotate already created widgets like Container so for the container by *transformAlignment*you can rotate widget.

- **RotationTransition**: which animates the rotation of a widget, mainly we prefer when we need rotation with animation transition.https://api.flutter.dev/flutter/widgets/RotationTransition-class.html
- **Transform.rotate**: which applies a rotation paint effect, they Create a widget that transforms its child using a rotation around the center.

**RotationTransition** Widget example:-

```
           RotationTransition(
                turns: AlwaysStoppedAnimation(15 / 360),
                child: Text("flutter is awesome")
           )
```

**Transform.rotate** Widget example :-

```
    Transform.rotate(
        angle: 15 * math.pi / 180, 
        child: Text("flutter is awesome")
          )
```

Comment: Both `RotationTransition` and `Transform.rotate` solutions are already provided earlier.

Answer (score 3):

```
Container(
          decoration: BoxDecoration(borderRadius: BorderRadius.circular(50), color: Color(0xffF6F8FF),),
          width: MediaQuery.of(context).size.width*0.6,
          height: MediaQuery.of(context).size.height*0.4,
          alignment:
          new Alignment(0, 0),
          transform:
          new Matrix4.translationValues(MediaQuery.of(context).size.width * 0.55, -250.0, 0.0)
              ..rotateZ(28 * 3.1415927 / 180),
          ),
```

Comment: Welcome to SO and thanks for your answer. Others may benefit from your answer even better which is why SO wants to discourage code-only answers. Would it be possible to add a brief explanation how this code solves the problem?