# flutter custom shape button in bottom navbar

Tags: flutter, widget, navigation-drawer, navbar, shapes

I have this design of a bottom nav bar(shown in photo) and I can't figure out how to make the custom shape button, here is my bottom navbar code

```
Scaffold(
      appBar: AppBar(
        title: Text("Reply demo"),
      ),
      bottomNavigationBar: BottomAppBar(
        elevation: 0,
        color: Color(0xff344955),
        child: Container(
          padding: EdgeInsets.symmetric(horizontal: 10.0),
          height: 56.0,
          child: Row(children: <Widget>[
            IconButton(
              onPressed: showMenu,
              icon: Icon(Icons.menu),
              color: Colors.white,
            ),
            Spacer(),
            IconButton(
              onPressed: () {},
              icon: Icon(Icons.add),
              color: Colors.white,
            ),
            IconButton(
              onPressed: () {},
              icon: Icon(Icons.home),
              color: Colors.white,
            )
          ]),
        ),
      ),
```

[image]

Comment: You need to create a custom widget that returns a container and as a child has a picture `home_photo.png`. You must rotate the widget 45 degree. To do that https://stackoverflow.com/questions/44276080/how-do-i-rotate-something-15-degrees-in-flutter