# Using Flutter, how can I paint text on canvas with rotation

Tags: flutter, canvas, text, rotation, angle

I am trying to point a text over a given canvas and I can not find any option to paint this text with an angle so that it will be tilted.

```
void drawText(Canvas canvas, Offset center, String text, Color color,
Color bgColor, double fontSize) {
TextSpan span = new TextSpan(
  style: new TextStyle(
      color: color,
      backgroundColor: bgColor,
      fontWeight: FontWeight.bold,
      fontSize: fontSize),
  text: text);
  TextPainter tp = new TextPainter(
      text: span,
      textAlign: TextAlign.center,
      textDirection: TextDirection.ltr);
   tp.layout();
   tp.paint(canvas, center);
}
```

I have this function which is working fine left to right in an ordinary way but how can I rotate it with an angle? For reference you can see the image. I want to do it like the highlighted text which is rotated.

I am aware of the fact that we can do it using widgets like a button but how about a canvas? Any help is appreciated, Thanks[image]

Comment: can you include an output image, it will help others to get easily?

Comment: Please see the added picture. Thanks

Comment: Try using `canavas.save()` and `canavs.restore()` function. [rotate a text](https://stackoverflow.com/a/57084666/13701072) and [save and restore](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/59650399/what-is-canvas-save-and-canvas-restore)

Answer (score 1):

```
Transform.rotate(
        angle: pi/2,
      child: customWeiget,
    );
```